# QDnsLookup not emitting finished(), infinite wait

Tags: qt

I have multiples DNS record (MX, CNAME , TXT) and I would like to read the TXT record content.

The lookup() function never emit finished(), I am using this code to test:

```
QDnsLookup m_dns = new QDnsLookup(this);
connect(m_dns, SIGNAL(finished()), this, SLOT(onHandle()));

m_dns->setType(QDnsLookup::TXT);
m_dns->setName("uol.com.br");
m_dns->lookup();

void Update::onHandle()
{
  if (m_dns->error() != QDnsLookup::NoError)
      qDebug() << m_dns->error() << m_dns->errorString();

  foreach (const QDnsServiceRecord &record, m_dns->serviceRecords())
    qDebug() << "Name:   " << record.name();

  emit handled();
}
```

If I use a online service to read the record, it works!

Answer (score 0):

The onHandle slot should be looking at m_dns->textRecords(), not m_dns->serviceRecords().

The correct code:

```
  foreach (const QDnsTextRecord &record , m_dns->textRecords()) {
    qDebug() << "Values: " << record.values();
    qDebug() << "Name:   " << record.name();
 }
```